# Change StatusBar color and show ActionMode at the same time

Tags: android

I change status bar color whenever action mode is shown using this piece of code:

```
override fun onActionModeStarted(mode: ActionMode?) {
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window?.statusBarColor = colorBlue
    }
}
```

The problem is action mode shows up with an animation while `window.statusBarColo =` changes status bar color immediately and as a result status bar color is changed a little bit sooner than action mode being displayed and it is so unpleasant to see. Do you guys have any solution for this?

Comment: Read android documentation : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui